# how to run new android ndk project using eclipse in mac os terminal

Tags: android, android-ndk

i have try to create new ndk project in eclipse i have done all the rules of ndk project need
i create project like this project [using this link](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/49.html)now my need is how to make project path  using mac os x terminal

i tried like this

```
cd projectpath
cd ndkpath
./ndk-build
```

but it showing this error

```
Android NDK: Please define the NDK_PROJECT_PATH variable to point to it.    
/Users/macbookpro/Documents/android-ndk-r7/build/core/build-local.mk:102: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
```

guide me where i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That usually happens when you are in wrong directory and are invoking ndk-build. Check that you have "jni" folder in your current directory (ndkpath folder in your example)

Take a look at how are samples from NDK structured. For example, hello-jni:

```
hello-jni
   |
   +--- jni
   |     |
   |     +--- Android.mk
   |     |
   |     +--- hello-jni.c
   |
   +--- res
   |     |
   |    ...
   |
   +--- src
   |     |
   |    ...
   |
   +--- AndroidManifest.xml
```

If you are using same structure then you must invoke ndk-build from top directory - hello-jni directory.

Comment: What happens if it is not? I have some libraries I have to compile and they are shared between the projects and they are two levels above jni folder.